# Matrix derivative of a special function

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, trace

I need some help for calculating the matrix derivative of a special function. 
I have checked Wikipedia and Matrix Cookbook, but could not get the answer or idea. Let us define $f(X)$ as

$$f(X)=tr(diag(X,X,X) B diag(X,X,X) C)$$

where tr( ) is the trace operator, $X$ is n by n matrix, $diag(X,X,X)$ is 3n by 3n block diagonal matrix, B and C are 3n by 3n matrix

What is the derivative with respect to $X$.

Any solution, idea or reference?

Many thanks!

Henry

Comment: Try computing $f(X+H)-f(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the $n\times n$ blocks of $B$ and $C$, this is $\sum_{ij}\operatorname{tr}XB_{ij}XC_{ji}$, so the derivative with respect to $X$ is

$$\sum_{ij}\left(B_{ij}XC_{ji}+C_{ij}XB_{ji}\right)^\top\;.$$

Comment: Thank you joriki. I forgot to try the most straightforward way. I tried to manipulate the properties of Kronecker product but just couldn't work it out.   The only confusion I have is the derivative you wrote. Transpose operator should be on the the second term inside the    parenthese

Comment: @Henry the expression that joriki has provided is correct.  The transpose operator is applied to everything inside the parentheses, and no term inside the parentheses needs an extra transpose.

Comment: @Henry: Perhaps the reordering I performed is confusing you. I first cyclically shifted the product under the trace to get the second occurrence of $X$ to the front ($XC_{ji}XB_{ij}$), and then I swapped $i$ and $j$ to exhibit the symmetry between $B$ and $C$ in the result. You can omit the swap and write the second term as $C_{ji}XB_{ij}$ if you prefer. In either case, there's no additional transpose, and it doesn't matter whether you apply the transpose to the sum (as I did) or to the terms individually.